# Jaxb + jersey. Skipping null fields in generated json

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey

I have a code:

```
   return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(errors).build();
```

Where: `Response` is comes from this package: `javax.ws.rs.core` (jersey 1.9.1);

Where the `errors` is instance of:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class UserInfoValidationErrors {

    @XmlElement String username;
    @XmlElement String email;
...
```

Then I have JSON result like this: `{"username":null,"email":"Email is not valid"}`

If there is a way how to avoid having `null` there?

Answer (score 6):

If you have Jersey configured to use Jackson to do it's JSON serialization, you can annotate your model classes with:

`@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)`

If you want to configure Jersey to use Jackson, you can update your web.xml as follows:

```
<servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.your.package;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `@XmlElement(nillable = true)`. At least this works for XML generation, so I believe it should work for JSON as well.

Comment: `@XmlElement(nillable=true)` would be something that I would specify to force `null` to be marshalled out (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/binding-to-json-xml-handling-null.html).  The default JAXB behaviour is not to marshal a node for null values.

Comment: Anyway it does not work for my case. Maybe because I don't use marshaling directly (by jaxb) but letting Jersey do this.

Comment: It seems this might be the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982199/jersey-response-for-empty-list-is-null-instead-of But I still don't get it, how to make all working together.

Comment: To interface with the calling application I needed to the nulls to be passed to the caller.  The above solution `@XmlElement(nillable=true)` worked for me on Jersey 2.17 using JAXB and MOXy for automatic conversion between a moderately complex Java object and JSON (and XML) serialization.